# What does the & mean when used in the end of a bash script?

Tags: bash, script

I use a bash script for launching and add a `&` to the end, like this:

```
./bin/Startup.sh par1 &
```

What does the `&` symbol in the end mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It tells the system to run the command in the background.  From the bash man page on my system:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell  does
>          not  wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.  Commands separated by a ; are executed sequentially; the shell waits
>          for each command to terminate in turn.  The return status is the exit status of the last command executed.